# Concerning the tag [conflict-of-interests]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tag [conflict-of-interests](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-of-interests) has an unnecessary and incorrect "s" at the end. **Would a Mod please remove the final "s".** The tag should be [conflict-of-interest](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-of-interest).

The [Tag Info](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/conflict-of-interests/info) is fine,

> Use this tag when asking about actual or potential conflicts of interest, as well as related questions regarding conflict of interest rules and ethics.

and correctly places the "s" for plural use after "conflict"; however, a plural is not needed for the tag name.